# MATLAB: How to randomize the rows of a matrix?

Tags: matlab

I'm looking for an efficient way to manipulate a 40x151 matrix so that the rows are randomly scrambled.

Comment: Well done @tashuhka for spotting the duplicate!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I worked out the answer just as I was about to post.

```
new_matrix = old_matrix(randperm(40),:)
```

Comment: +1 for thinking of `randperm` and not `randi`. The latter can sometimes give repeated values, which will cause your matrix rows to be repeated while shuffling.